# Why "tr" "onmouseover" event does not trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table:

```
<table id="someId" class="someClass" style="width:50%" border=1>
        <tr id="data">  
          <td>Row 0, Column 0</td>
          <td>Row 0, Column 1</td>
          <td>Row 0, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="data">  
            <td>Row 1, Column 0</td>
            <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="data">  
            <td>Row 2, Column 0</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I use the follwoing Jquery to implement the feature that **when mouse over a row, the row background color will change**:

```
$("tr#data").onmouseover(
             function() {
                 $(this).css('bgcolor', '#77FF99');
             }
         );
```

I have also tried "hover" both are not working, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Try using `class="data"` instead of `id="data"`.

```
<table id="someId" class="someClass" style="width:50%" border=1>
        <tr class="data">  
          <td>Row 0, Column 0</td>
          <td>Row 0, Column 1</td>
          <td>Row 0, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">  
            <td>Row 1, Column 0</td>
            <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">  
            <td>Row 2, Column 0</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Also, the `onmouseover` function does not exists, use `mouseover` instead. And the `bgcolor` property in CSS is `background-color`.

You may also want to add a `mouseout` function to cancel the effect of the `mouseover`:

```
$("tr.data").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#77FF99');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
});
```

Try it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2zuCb/

Comment: Thanks! I checked the reference here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp which said there is "onmouseover" function for "tr" element, it seems this reference is wrong.

Comment: jQuery event names and HTML event handler attribute names are not the same thing. Always refer to the jQuery documentation to make sure.